# Java wants certain objects to be final

Tags: java, swing, oop

I am building a GUI-application and I am needing two objects from other classes I have written.

The GUI is written in a method which is called by the main-method, in that method I have initialized my two Objects.

Basicly Eclipse tells me that it

```
 "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable user defined in an enclosing scope"
```

The GUI has a Button which on press brings up another window, wher the user can put in his login information.

The login information is then taken and processed with the help of one of the objects that java/eclipse tells me to make final, but when they're final I cannot use them the way I want.

Where else should I initialize my objects or what can I do that I can make use of the objects, so that theyre not final.

Heres the code in question:

Usermanager and Player are the objects that I have said problems with

package de.unistuttgart.iaas.icetea.gui;

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import de.unistuttgart.iaas.icetea.player.Player;
import de.unistuttgart.iaas.icetea.user.UserManager;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ICT_mainGUI extends JFrame {
    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    /**
     * Launch the application. should open a window (hopefully)
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // java eventq shit
        // TODO DONT TOUCH THIS SHIT
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ICT_mainGUI frame = new ICT_mainGUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public ICT_mainGUI() {
        // initializing needed objects
        // user manager for admin and user shit
        // player for player manipulation
        // TODO DONT TOUCH THIS EITHER

        UserManager user = new UserManager();
        Player player = new Player();

        getContentPane().setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 933, 112);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
        panel_1.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);
        panel_1.setFocusTraversalPolicyProvider(true);
        getContentPane().add(panel_1);
        panel_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 5, 5));

        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        panel_1.add(playButton);

        JButton btnPause = new JButton("Pause");
        panel_1.add(btnPause);

        JButton btnStop = new JButton("Stop");
        panel_1.add(btnStop);

        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        panel_1.add(progressBar);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.setBorderPainted(false);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        menuBar.add(panel);

        JButton signInButton = new JButton("Anmelden");
        signInButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        //seting up our window
                        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login User");
                        frame.setSize(300, 200);


                        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                        frame.add(panel);
                        panel.setLayout(null);

                //userlabel 
                JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
                userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
                panel.add(userLabel);

                JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
                userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
                panel.add(userText);

                JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password");
                passwordLabel.setBounds(10, 40, 80, 25);
                panel.add(passwordLabel);

                JPasswordField passwordText = new JPasswordField(20);
                passwordText.setBounds(100, 40, 160, 25);
                panel.add(passwordText);

                //PASSWORDREPEAT
                JPasswordField passwordrepeat = new JPasswordField(20);
                //TODO fix orientation
                passwordrepeat.setBounds(100, 70, 160,25);
                panel.add(passwordrepeat);
                passwordrepeat.setEnabled(false);

                //passwordtextrepeat
                JLabel passwordtextrepeat = new JLabel("Repeat Password");

                //TODO fix orientation
                passwordtextrepeat.setBounds(10, 70, 80, 25);
                panel.add(passwordtextrepeat);
                passwordtextrepeat.setEnabled(false);

                JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
                loginButton.setBounds(10, 100, 90, 25);
                panel.add(loginButton);

                JButton registerButton = new JButton("add User");
                registerButton.setBounds(180, 100, 80, 25);
                panel.add(registerButton);
                registerButton.setEnabled(false);


                frame.setVisible(true);

                //doing verification stuff

                final String username = userText.getText();
                final String password = passwordLabel.getText();

                loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        user.addUser(username, password);

                        if (user.getCurrentUser().equals(username)) {
                            String stringfordialog = "Login sucessful \n Current User:\n" + user.getCurrentUser();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, stringfordialog);

                        } else {

                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });

        panel.add(signInButton);

        JButton signOutButton = new JButton("Abmelden");
        panel.add(signOutButton);

        JButton adduserButton = new JButton("AddUser");

        if (user.isAdmin()) {
            adduserButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            adduserButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
        panel.add(adduserButton);

        adduserButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFrame adduserdialog = new JFrame("AddUser");
                adduserdialog.setSize(400, 200);
                setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            }
        });
        // TODO promote User
        JButton promoteUserButton = new JButton("Promote User");

        if (user.isAdmin()) {
            promoteUserButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            promoteUserButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        panel.add(promoteUserButton);

        JSlider volumeSlider = new JSlider();
        menuBar.add(volumeSlider);
        // close button
        JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
        btnClose.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        menuBar.add(btnClose);
        // TODO **finished** close the window
        btnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem?

Comment: Mark `user` and `player` as final.  It might help to learn about breaking up your code more as well - that was a bit of a nightmare to read through to find what variables where being used where.

Comment: okay I think I got confused in my own thoughts, can final objects still be manipulated, do they work just as fine as other objects ?

Comment: being final doesn't make an object immutable. It just means the variable / parameter that is declared final cannot be reassigned (ie using `xxx = somethingNew`

Comment: so I would be just fine leaving them final ? because I got scared I couldnt call the objects methods on things

Comment: It's absolutely fine. I've often done this in my swing GUIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this before. Here's what's happening.

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
ActionListener al = new ActionListener(ActionEvent ae) {
  actopnPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    bar.setX(x);
  }
}
```

The problem is that the code in the action listener isn't going to get called immediately, and the foo variable could have changed by the time that bar.setX is called... They're in two different scopes. So to make sure that the code in the ActionListener has the proper reference to the object it's going to call setX on, you need to declare bar as final - ie it won't, cannot change.

Comment: @zython - By the way, in Java 8, the restriction loosens: It will be sufficient for the local variable to be *effectively final*, rather than needing to be explicitly declared final.

Answer (score 2):

Your anonymous inner class (listener) refers to its enclosing scope by taking copies of the local variables.
When the anonymous method returns, your local variables will be cleaned up from the [stack](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/difference-between-stack-and-heap-java.html), so they won't exist anymore. But the anonymous class objects `UserManager` and `Player` references these variables. It's wrong behavior so Java doesn't allow you to do this.

After it is final it becomes a constant. So it is storing in the heap and can be safely used in anonymous classes.

Comment: I think I fixed it by writing

class{
private UserManager user;
private Player player;
}

and in the method

this.user = new UserManager();
this.player = new Player();

that somehow made any errors go away

also would the objects behave normally, because I have a hashset and a hashmap in the object that I dont know what happens to it 

sorry for being confusing I dont know how to better express myself

Comment: When you type long code, please edit your question instead because it's very hard to understand like this. Anyway I'm very happy it worked out! And happy to help (: